# Rails Storing Years Incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a Rails 4 application and am trying to have an admin select appointment times.

```
...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :start_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :end_time %>
  </div>
...
```

My model doesn't do anything with the date except validate it's presence. 
In my database (Sqlite), it stores them as time objects.

My controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
  @appointment = @user.appointments.build(appointment_params)
  ...
end
...

def appointment_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:start_time, :end_time, :comments)
end
```

I have changed the default time zone to:

```
config.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

**Problem**

I create via the form and then check in the Rails console like this:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.2)
>> appointment = Appointment.all.last
Appointment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "appointments".* FROM "appointments"    ORDER BY "appointments"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Appointment id: 8, user_id: 1, comments: "", start_time: "2000-01-01 12:50:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 12:50:00">
>> appointment.start_time.year
=> 2000
```

I get this even though I selected (and it's by default) 2015. Why is Rails storing the year as always 2000?

**Edit** - Migration

```
class ChangeTimeInAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    remove_column :appointments, :time
    add_column :appointments, :start_time, :time
    add_column :appointments, :end_time, :time
  end
 end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.text    "comments"
  t.time    "start_time"
  t.time    "end_time"
end
```

Comment: can you show the migration? I think that you are using a time field instead of a DateTime

Comment: Examine (print) the value of `params` in `appointment_params`. I bet you get `start_date(1i)` and similar.

Comment: Ok, so Time doesn't store year information that's datetime.  OK, won't forget that again.

Comment: Time does store the year.

Comment: So changing the datatype to datetime worked.  It will just default to 2000-1-1 if time is the datatype.

Comment: @Jordan: A `time` inside the database should be a simple time-of-day (i.e. no year, no month, no day) but Ruby doesn't have a time-of-day type so a date-time ends up being used in Ruby. A Ruby `Time` instance will have a year but a database `time` column won't.

Comment: @muistooshort You're correct, of course. Thanks for the clarification.